# Connect a mongo atlas connection to play framework app

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, reactivemongo

I can successfully connect a *standalone cluster* to my *Play Framework (2.7)* app (with *ReactiveMongo 0.17.1*) and I can connect *Mongo Compass* to my replica set (created in *MongoDb Atlas*) but am having big problems connecting my *MongoDb Atlas* replica set to my *Play Framework* app. This should be a case of using the `connection string` in the `application.conf` file; i.e.

`mongodb.uri = <connectionString>`

In fact the [ReactiveMongo documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/mongodb-atlas.html) describes it as:

`mongodb.uri = "mongodb+srv://${ATLAS_USERNAME}:${ATLAS_PASSWORD}@cluster0-p8ccg.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`

- *with 3 variables of `${ATLAS_USERNAME}`, `${ATLAS_PASSWORD}` & `test` (default database name)*

And the *MongoDb Atlas* documentation (when logged in) describes the `connection string` as being formulated like so:

`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.pwe0y.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

- *with 3 variables of `<username>`, `<password>` & `myFirstDatabase` (default database name)*

So aside from some variable differences in the addresses (I use the one from *Atlas* as it is distinctive to my details)

The recurring error reads:

`[error] r.c.a.MongoDBSystem - [Supervisor-1/Connection-2] Fails to send a isMaster request to cluster0-shard-00-01.pwe0y.mongodb.net:27017 (channel #ac1cfe76) javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine closed already at reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(...)(Unknown Source)`

Things to note:

- I have node.js v12.14.1
- the user is granted the appropriate permissions
- option parameters have also been `URL encoded` tested
- my ip address is in the `IP Access List` (in Mongo Atlas)

Comment: How are you connecting to MongoDB Atlas?  Is your app on-premises or in the cloud (AWS, Azure, GCP, etc.)?  Do you use VPC Peering, or private end point?  If you are attempting to connect to Atlas across the internet did you allow the application's public IP address access to Atlas in the `Network Access` area (whitelist)?

Comment: @barrypicker Thanks. I do recall having those options when setting up the DB but I can't recall what I chose. How could I find out (it wasn't obvious when I looked around or online for an answer)? I am using the free version currently for development purposes - M0 Sandbox

Comment: when in the cluster view, look to the left to see `Network Access`.  Here you can add your app's public IP address to allow traffic.  You must be able to distinguish between a private IP and a public IP.  You can see your public IP address when navigating to https://whatismyipaddress.com/

Comment: @barrypicker - sorry I should have also added that my ip address is already in the `IP Access List`

Comment: Please check if this is relevant: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SCALA-501

Answer (score -1):

For connection you should just pass the `mongodb.uri` as this:

```
mongodb.uri = "mongodb+srv://${ATLAS_USERNAME}:${ATLAS_PASSWORD}@cluster0-p8ccg.mongodb.net"
```

don't use the full connection string URL for the connection.

Answer (score -1):

If Atlas doesn't set `authSource=admin` in the DNS SRV, make sure the add `?authSource=admin` to the connection URI.

Also note that, 0.17 is more than two years old, won't get fix.